# Qt Balloon Window from QFrame

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, qwidget, qframe

I would like to create my own Balloon window for tips in Qt. I'm starting by creating a window with round corners.

I'm using a class inherited from QFrame. The class's constructor contains:

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
Pal.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::yellow);
this->setAutoFillBackground(true);
this->setPalette(Pal);
this->setStyleSheet("QFrame {border-style: solid; border-width: 10px;"
                    "border-radius: 100px;"
                    "min-width: 10em; background-clip: padding; background-origin: content;}");
```

But this is not creating round corners when showing using the `show()` member function. I'm getting this:

[image]

How can I get rid of those rectangular edges and have them transpararent colored?

If you require any additional information, please ask.

Comment: I doubt what you want is possible without some custom drawing in paintEvent().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my guess is correct you are looking for something like [`setMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask) !

Basically what you need to do is draw a rectangle with your desired radius and then convert it to QRegion to use it with setMask. See below one way:

```
QPainterPath path;
path.addRoundedRect(rect(), 100, 100);
QRegion region = QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon());
setMask(region);
```

And that will be the result:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Works. But only for top-level widgets.

Comment: The OP are trying to do it with a frameless window. It not satisfy?

Comment: Yep. I was overthinking it. Nowadays I do all my gui stuff with qml. Much easier to do stuff like that.

Comment: Thank you. This works, except that the window is smaller than the original one. Do you know how the size of this can be determined?

Comment: The minimum size should be the diameter associated to the radius of the rounded corner, in your case the minimum size should be 200 for both width and height (and this way you'll get a circle).

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
auto frame = new QWidget(parent, Qt::Popup); 
frame->setStyleSheet("background-color: red; border: 1px solid green; border-radius: 6px;");

QPainterPath path; 
path.addRoundedRect(frame->rect(), 6, 6); 
frame->setMask(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon());

frame->show();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.